# How do I compare a string variable to a string variable that is stored in a object that is in a arraylist in java

Tags: java

for example say I have

```
String s = "hey"; 
...
List<FacebookPerson> list = new ArrayList<FacebookPerson>();
```

and I want to see if one of the objects in the list already has the paramater of "hey"

Comment: Hint for premature-answerers: if you suspect that code examples in question should contain generic types and question doesn't properly format these examples then take a look at [edit] option to peek at original example. Remember that browser can't print `<...>` because it sees it as tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "hey";
for (String temp : list) {
   boolean status = temp.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase());
   if (status)
       System.out.println("Match Found!");

}
```

Try this .

Comment: It is saying I cant convert my FacebookPerson object to a String @sean

Comment: You need to @override toString in your FacebookPerson Object. See http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55